# Настроить toggle анимацию

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

У меня возникла проблема с анимацией. Я использую bootstrap для того чтобы создать учебный сайтик и никак не могу понять, как бы сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на "Выбрать несколько" открывались все колапсы внутри одной карточки (завтраки, обеды и тд). Я видимо не вижу ошибки, но он открывает только 1-ый элемент
[ссылка на гит](https://github.com/artisakov/vigilant-journey)

```
    <div class="card m-3 h-100" style="width: 26rem;">
      <img src="static/images/img1.jpg" class="card-img-top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Понедельник</h5>
        <p style='font-size: 1.3rem;'>{{m}}</p>
        <form method="POST" action="/delete">
          <button type="button" id="toggle" class="btn btn-outline-primary mb-3 mr-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne collapseTwo collapseThree collapseFour" >Выбрать несколько</button>
          <button type="submit" id="delete" class="btn btn-outline-danger  mb-3" style="display: none;">Удалить</button>
          <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Завтраки
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse multi-collapse" aria-label="collapseOne"
                data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                  {%for i in MondayZ%}
                  <input name='checked' style="display: none;" class="checkbox" type='checkbox' id='{{ i[0] }}'
                    value='{{ i[0] }}/{{ i[3] }}/{{ i[2] }}/{{i[4]}}'>
                  <label name='checked' for='{{ i[0] }}'>{{ i[0] }} {{i[2]}}</label><br>
                  {%endfor%}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Обеды
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse multi-collapse" aria-label="collapseTwo" 
                data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                  {%for i in MondayO%}
                  <input name='checked' style="display: none;" class="checkbox" type='checkbox' id='{{ i[0] }}'
                    value='{{ i[0] }}/{{ i[3] }}/{{ i[2] }}/{{i[4]}}'>
                  <label name='checked' for='{{ i[0] }}'>{{ i[0] }} {{i[2]}}</label><br>
                  {%endfor%}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Ужины
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-label="collapseThree" 
                data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                  {%for i in MondayY%}
                  <input name='checked' style="display: none;" class="checkbox" type='checkbox' id='{{ i[0] }}'
                    value='{{ i[0] }}/{{ i[3] }}/{{ i[2] }}/{{i[4]}}'>
                  <label name='checked' for='{{ i[0] }}'>{{ i[0] }} {{i[2]}}</label><br>
                  {%endfor%}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                    Перекусы
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-label="collapseFour" 
                data-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="card-body">
                  {%for i in MondayP%}
                  <input name='checked' style="display: none;" class="checkbox" type='checkbox' id='{{ i[0] }}'
                    value='{{ i[0] }}/{{ i[3] }}/{{ i[2] }}/{{i[4]}}'>
                  <label name='checked' for='{{ i[0] }}'>{{ i[0] }} {{i[2]}}</label><br>
                  {%endfor%}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты пытаешься "поженить" бустраповские панели с "мультиколаппсом" и "аккордеон". По итогу оно работает не так, как ожидалось. Предлагаю перейти частично на JavaScript, отказавшись от multi-collapse. 
Кнопка `<button type="button" id="toggle" ...>...</button>` освобождается от управления бустраповскими элементами через атрибуты тэга. Это будет просто кнопка с id, по которому наш JS код будет искать все подходящие элементы в аккордеоне и менять их состояние с открытого на закрытое и обратно

```
$('#toggle').on('click', function () {
    $('.accordion .collapse').collapse('toggle');
});
```

Вот здесь инфа по этому способу: [Bootstrap4 docs](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Кроме того можно удалить ставшие ненужными атрибуты тэгов касательно "multi-collapse".

Рабочий вариант лежит [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/Reanimatolog501/bdsuhqLn/1/)